# Making a PC3 ram stick work in a pc3l slot with given voltage 1.5V

Tags: memory

So I have an old laptop which recently died and I wish to increase my current laptop's RAM, with the RAM upgrade I gave the old one.
Both the sticks are 4GB DDR3 with same speeds. However in the new one(Lenovo) the stick is PC3L but the slot is labelled as 1.5V DDR3.
So, theoretically the other stick should work right? But it isn't even detecting it.
I am running Ubuntu 17.04 btw.

Comment: "So, theoretically the other stick should work right?" - No; You are mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

DDR3L memory will work in DDR3 and DDR3L Slots
DDR3 will work only in DDR3 slot (1.5v slot).